# Nuxt JS Добавить своё мета свойство в один конкретный роутер

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Нужно добавить на одном конкретном роуте своё мета свойство.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в файле nuxt.config.js прописал:

```
router: {
  extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
    routes.push({
              path: '/app',
              component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/app/index.vue'),
              meta: {
                test: 'asdasd'
              }
    })
  }
}
```

Эффекта никакого.

Если так:

```
  router: {
    extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
      return [
        {
          name: 'app',
          path: '/app', 
          component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/app/index.vue'),          
          meta: {
            test: 'asdasd'
          }
        },
      ]
    }
  },
```

то работает, но теряются все остальные роуты, это придётся вообще все  роуты  вручную вписывать, а их оч много. Что можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Используя [Локальные настройки](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/meta-tags-seo#local-settings) в компоненте (`pages/app/index.vue`), который указан, для вашего особенного роута, заполните свойство `head`, чтобы сформировать особенные метаданные для этого роута:

```
<script>
export default {
  ...
  head: {
    meta: [
      {
        hid: 'test',
        name: 'test',
        content: 'asdasd'
      },
      ...
    ],
  }
}
</script>
```

При использовании `head` как метода - вы получаете доступ к контексту `this` и соответственно к существующим, в нем, данным:

```
<script>
    export default {
      data(){
       return {
        test: 'asdasd'
       }
      },
      head() {
       return {
         meta: [
          {
            hid: 'test',
            name: 'test',
            content: this.test
          },
          ...
        ],
       }
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Более подробно вы можете прочитать в [документации Nuxt - Мета-теги и SEO](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/meta-tags-seo)

Answer (score 0):

Да, выше хорощий пример, как нужно сделать. Просто нужно определить `head` как функцию, и там динамически подставлять данные из meta роутера.

Потому, что если определить `head` как функцию, то получаем доступ к контексту приложения `nuxt` + `this` локального компонента.

Советую почитать [статью](https://badcode.ru/kak-rabotat-s-mieta-tieghami-v-prilozhienii-nuxt/), как работать с мета-тегами в приложении Nuxt. Там даже пример к похожим контекстом приведён.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: понял, благодарю, буду дальше разбираться, помогать ответами :)
удивляет настолько быстрая реакция на ответ, круто!